StreamBuilder doesn't refresh automatically in my drawer
I build a drawer that contains friends requests and I would like to update it automatically when a new friend request is sent to my user.
I build this Drawer widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:opinions/provider/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:opinions/user/user_model.dart';
import 'package:opinions/widgets/avatar_logo.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class FriendsRequestDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "friends_request_drawer";

  const FriendsRequestDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  State<FriendsRequestDrawer> createState() => _FriendsRequestDrawerState();
}

class _FriendsRequestDrawerState extends State<FriendsRequestDrawer> {
  late Stream<List<UserAccount>> userStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userStream = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).getFindsRequestsAccountsStream();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: StreamBuilder<List<UserAccount>>(
        stream: userStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"));
          }
          final userAccount = snapshot.data ?? [];
          if (userAccount.isEmpty) {
            return Center(child: Text("No Find Requests"));
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: userAccount.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: AvatarLogo(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  border: null,
                  backgroundImage: userAccount[index].photoURL == null
                      ? null
                      : AssetImage(userAccount[index].photoURL!),
                ),
                title: Text(userAccount[index].pseudo),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

With these Stream functions:
Stream<List<UserAccount>> getFindsRequestsAccountsStream() async* {
    if (userAccount != null && userAccount!.findsRequest.isNotEmpty) {
      List<UserAccount> findsRequestsAccounts = [];
      for (Map<String, String> element in userAccount!.findsRequest) {
        try {
          UserAccount newUser = await DbHelper
              .getStreamUser(element['uid']!)
              .first;
          findsRequestsAccounts.add(newUser);
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error fetching user: $e');
        }
      }
      yield findsRequestsAccounts;
    } else {
      yield [];
    }
  }

et cette fonction pour récupérer les données de ma database :
static Stream<UserAccount> getStreamUser(String uid) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collectionUser)
        .doc(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => UserAccount.fromJson(snapshot.data()!));
  }

I don't understand why my data don't get refresh automatically in my drawer when I add (manually) a new friend request in my database. It only refreshes it when I leave and enter a new time in my drawer. Thanks for your help
